# SWIG Losing Scope of Structures

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to create an interface between a protocol parser written in C++ and a TCP packet filter written in Python. I am unfamiliar with using C++ with python, and have been trying to make the two cooperate for several days now.

I am using the swig library. The parsing class (I didn't write) contains many references to other c++ files through header files. The C++ class is called E2ProtocolHandler.cpp and has a header file containing all dependancies called E2ProtocolHandler.h.

I wrote the following Swig interface to comply with this:

```
%module e2ParserSwig

%{
#include "E2ProtocolHandler.h"
%}

bool parseE2(std::vector<uint8_t> ui8BufferIn, TTCAPMessage_t &tcapMsg);
```

Running this gives me no problems:

```
swig -c++ -python -o e2Parser_wrap.cpp e2ParserSwig.i
```

Compiling is where the scope issues occur:

```
g++ -c -fPIC e2Parser_wrap.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/lib/python2.6
```

Error:

```
e2Parser_wrap.cpp:6607: error: ‘TTCAPComponent_t’ was not declared in this scope
```

The `TTCAPCompnent_t` structure is defined in `E2ProtocolHandler.h`
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out purely out of luck. I know C fairly well but I have never used C++. That being said "::" is a foreign concept to me, or was a foreign concept to me.

In order to fix the issue I needed to include the namespace the function is under. I don't think anyone could have derived that from my question above because I didn't post the source code for integrity purposes.

The Swig interface should have been:

```
%module e2ParserSwig

%{
#include "E2ProtocolHandler.h"
%}

bool E2ProtocolHandler::parseE2(std::vector<uint8_t> ui8BufferIn, TTCAPMessage_t &tcapMsg);
```